# Is PLT Hook legit in a developer tool?

Tags: c, security, hook

I'm writing a Python library to help Python developers find bugs in their code. The user adds the library to his Python code entry point and then receives insights about possible bugs.

In order to do that, I use a PLT Hook library (https://github.com/kubo/plthook) to find out when Python code makes system calls. The library hooks system calls in the Python program's process the developer added my library to.

I'm trying to find out whether it's something that smells bad in the security aspect. If a developer would like to use such a library in an organization where you are the CISO, what would you think about it? Is it legit?

Comment: Would that library be used in production or only in development?

Comment: Development only @dan1st